localhost:3000 not working when I start a docker container for my Rails project
I was following a tutorial on how to Dockerize a brand new Rails 7 app. I made the Docker container 'distant-mirror' Setting up the Docker container took about two hours, but now I entered in my Ubuntu terminal docker-compose up and I'm seeing this:
Starting demo-postgres-14.2 ... done
Starting distant_mirror_distant-mirror_1 ... done
Attaching to demo-postgres-14.2, distant_mirror_distant-mirror_1
demo-postgres-14.2 |
demo-postgres-14.2 | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
demo-postgres-14.2 |
demo-postgres-14.2 | 2024-07-10 04:38:13.141 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 10.3.1 20211027, 64-bit
demo-postgres-14.2 | 2024-07-10 04:38:13.141 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
demo-postgres-14.2 | 2024-07-10 04:38:13.141 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
demo-postgres-14.2 | 2024-07-10 04:38:13.237 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
demo-postgres-14.2 | 2024-07-10 04:38:13.304 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-07-10 04:34:48 UTC
demo-postgres-14.2 | 2024-07-10 04:38:13.326 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
demo-postgres-14.2 | 2024-07-10 04:38:14.830 UTC [28] ERROR:  database "distantmirror_production" already exists
demo-postgres-14.2 | 2024-07-10 04:38:14.830 UTC [28] STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "distantmirror_production" ENCODING = 'unicode'
distant-mirror_1  | Database 'distantmirror_production' already exists
distant-mirror_1  | => Booting Puma
distant-mirror_1  | => Rails 8.0.0.alpha application starting in production
distant-mirror_1  | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
distant-mirror_1  | [1] Puma starting in cluster mode...
distant-mirror_1  | [1] * Puma version: 6.4.2 (ruby 3.3.4-p94) ("The Eagle of Durango")
distant-mirror_1  | [1] *  Min threads: 3
distant-mirror_1  | [1] *  Max threads: 3
distant-mirror_1  | [1] *  Environment: production
distant-mirror_1  | [1] *   Master PID: 1
distant-mirror_1  | [1] *      Workers: 8
distant-mirror_1  | [1] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
distant-mirror_1  | [1] * Preloading application
distant-mirror_1  | [1] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
distant-mirror_1  | [1] Use Ctrl-C to stop
distant-mirror_1  | [1] - Worker 0 (PID: 24) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
distant-mirror_1  | [1] - Worker 1 (PID: 27) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
distant-mirror_1  | [1] - Worker 2 (PID: 34) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
distant-mirror_1  | [1] - Worker 3 (PID: 45) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
distant-mirror_1  | [1] - Worker 4 (PID: 57) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
distant-mirror_1  | [1] - Worker 5 (PID: 70) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
distant-mirror_1  | [1] - Worker 6 (PID: 81) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
distant-mirror_1  | [1] - Worker 7 (PID: 92) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0

But when I go to localhost:3000 on Chrome, I'm getting this screen:

Here is my docker-compose.yml file for reference:
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.2-alpine
    container_name: demo-postgres-14.2
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: 
      "postgres -c 'max_connections=500'"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  distant-mirror:
    build: .
    command: "./bin/rails server"
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - RAILS_MASTER_KEY=${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
    volumes:
      - app-storage:/rails/storage
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
  app-storage: {}

And here is my Dockerfile just in case:
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

# This Dockerfile is designed for production, not development. Use with Kamal or build'n'run by hand:
# docker build -t my-app .
# docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name my-app -e RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<value from config/master.key> my-app

# For a containerized dev environment, see Dev Containers: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started_with_devcontainer.html

# Make sure RUBY_VERSION matches the Ruby version in .ruby-version
ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.3.4
FROM docker.io/library/ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim AS base

# Rails app lives here
WORKDIR /rails

# Install base packages
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl libjemalloc2 libvips postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

# Set production environment
ENV RAILS_ENV="production" \
    BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1" \
    BUNDLE_PATH="/usr/local/bundle" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development"

# Throw-away build stage to reduce size of final image
FROM base AS build

# Install packages needed to build gems
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential bash bash-completion tzdata postgresql nodejs npm yarn git libpq-dev pkg-config && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

# Install application gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install && \
    rm -rf ~/.bundle/ "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/cache "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git && \
    bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile

# Copy application code
COPY . .

# Precompile bootsnap code for faster boot times
RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/

# Precompiling assets for production without requiring secret RAILS_MASTER_KEY
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile




# Final stage for app image
FROM base

# Copy built artifacts: gems, application
COPY --from=build "${BUNDLE_PATH}" "${BUNDLE_PATH}"
COPY --from=build /rails /rails

# Run and own only the runtime files as a non-root user for security
RUN groupadd --system --gid 1000 rails && \
    useradd rails --uid 1000 --gid 1000 --create-home --shell /bin/bash && \
    chown -R rails:rails db log storage tmp
USER 1000:1000

# Entrypoint prepares the database.
ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-entrypoint"]

# Start the server by default, this can be overwritten at runtime
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]


I read suggestions to move the Dockerfile into the app folder, but I tried that and it still wasn't working. Also I'm doubting that that would be the solution, since I work on another Rails project, and the Dockerfile is clearly in the main project folder and NOT within /app.
There wasn't really much for me to try other than changing the port numbers. I'm very new to how Docker works for Rails projects.
Any help would be appreciated!

When did you add the ports section? May be after container was already built?

What rails version are you using to deploy this container?
